# Why is the symbol map in Atiyah–Singer paper continuous?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ap.analysis-of-pdes, index-theory

I am reading ["Index of elliptic operators: I", by Atiyah and Singer](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970715) these days and I am trying to understand all the paper. I find it difficult to verify the following statement on page  512:

> Let $X$ be compact and $E$, $F$ be vector bundles over $X$, then the symbol
> $$ \sigma:\mathcal{P}_s^m(X;E,F) \rightarrow \operatorname{Symb}^m(X;E,F)$$
> is continuous for the sup norm topology on the unit sphere bundle of $T^*X$; it extends by continuity to a map $$\sigma_s:\overline{\mathcal{P}_s^m}(X;E,F) \rightarrow \overline {\operatorname{Symb}^m}(X;E,F)$$ with kernel equal to compact operators $H_s \rightarrow H_{s-m}$.

**Notation.** $\mathcal{P}_s^m(X;E,F)$ is the space of pseudo-differential operators of order $m$ considered as a map $$H_{s}(X;E) \rightarrow H_{s-m}(X;F) $$
and $\overline{\mathcal{P}_s^m}(X;E,F)$ is its completion under the operator norm topology.

I know how to prove that when $m=s=0$ except for the kernel statement where I am not sure how to proceed — I can see why the kernel is a subset of set of compact operators, but cannot see the equality. I can show also that the kernel contains all differential elliptic operators of order $m-1$ ( I wonder if the closure of the latter is exactly the compact operators).

I will be thankful for any help, It would be great if you give me a hint how to prove this may be even when $X$ is a domain of euclidean space and $E$, $F$ are trivial line bundles.

Comment: I think if you (pre- and post-) compose your operator with powers $(\Delta+1)^t$ for real $t$ and $\Delta$ being the Laplacian of any given Riemann metric, you can reduce the question to the case $m=s=0$.

Comment: That's an idea that come to me too, but I still didn't work it out. I will try it. Do you have any idea about that kernel statement ?

Comment: It may be in volume 3 of Hormander's book "Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators"